# Exception while getting bean from context, when bean name passed dynamically

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

i have below code.

Interface

```
@Component
public interface Service {
    public String getConfig();
}
```

2 implementation

```
@Service("UserService")
  public class userService implements Service{
        @Override
        public String getConfig() {
            // logic goes here
         return "result";
        }
}
```

customer implementation

```
@Service("CustomerService")
public class userService implements Service{
    @Override
    public String getConfig() {
        // logic goes here
     return "result";
    }
}
```

I have a configuration class where i need the bean dynamically

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {
    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context;
    @Bean
    public  Service getConfigBean(final String configName) {
        Service service = (Service) context.getBean(configName);
        return service;
    }
}
```

from my controller/any other class i just want get the bean object

```
   @RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST)
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    MyConfig myConfig;

    @Autowired
    Service  service;

    @RequestMapping(produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML , method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getInitiate()
    {
        service =  stateConversationConfig.getConfigBean("UserService");      // will get this String dynamically or based on logic
        System.out.println("service object : "+service);
        return "ok";
    }
}
```

But when i run my application on tomcat, its failed to deploy with following exception

```
   SEVERE: Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'getConfigBean' defined in class path resource [xxx/xxx/xxx/xxxxx.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [java.lang.String]: : No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:464)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
    at xx.xxx.xxxx.xxx.xxx.main(Application.java:36)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
```

Am I doing something wrong.?

Comment: Pay attention to the java naming Conventions. Class names should start with uppercase letter

Comment: Remove `@Autowired` from the `Service` field in your controller. You are setting it in the method so you don't want auto wiring...

Answer (score 0):

Beans are objects managed by Spring IoC container. When application context is created, beans are constructed, but Spring cannot create your `configBean` as it does not know what value should be passed to `configName`.

If you want dynamic services, I suggest that you create 2 separate beans (`userServices` and `customerService`) and a normal function (not with `@Bean`) `getConfigBean(String configName)`.

Comment: Hoang,  Thanks for your help.. it seems i was looking for functionality which is not possible in spring. Thanks for your suggestion.